# update semicolon separated IDs in a column - sql

Tags: sql

I've been trying to figure this problem out for a while now. Hope anyone can help here please.

I have an semicolon separated CategoryIDs in my Article table (e.g. ;2;34;5;9;), and I have a Category table with the old CategoryID column and the new CategoryID column. Now I'd like to update the CategoryIDs in the Article table with some new CategoryID based on the original CategoryIDs. e.g. (e.g. ;2;34;5;9;) will be updated to (e.g. ;564;344;753;944;)

The reason that I need this is because I'm merging tables from two databases with the same tables set ups.

I know this is a bad design, but it's been like this for ages. I can't really think of a solution for this, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you should really normalise your data

Comment: This is a good example of when "its too much trouble" to create a relationship table, in this case between Articles and Categories. In my experience this type of time saving Q.D.F. will eat up many more hours than if it was just done "properly" in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it's sql Server. 

btw, totally agree with James. This database was designed 7 years ago, maybe it was acceptable design at that time...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a bad design.

I suppose you use MySQL. I've used [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) MySQL featured function but [you can emulate it in MSSQL also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005). And I suppose you need to replace ALL old Id's with new.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15515/1)

Tables:

```
create table article(id int, CategoryID varchar(200));
create table Category(OldCategoryId int, newCategoryId int);
```

and update to replace groups:

```
update article,
(select 
  article.id, 
  CONCAT(';',
         GROUP_CONCAT(cast(newCategoryID as char) separator ';'),
         ';') newGroups 
from category
left join article on CategoryId like CONCAT('%;',CAST(oldCategoryId as char),';%')
group by article.id) t1
SET article.CategoryId=t1.newGroups
where article.id=t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

> [For such matters MySQL provides the function `find_in_set`. However SQL Server (if that's what you are working with) does not directly support an `IN` predicate for `CSV`, neither it provides `find_in_set`. It needs a `rowset` for `IN` predicate to work..](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/23/in-with-a-comma-separated-list-sql-server/).

Check on the above link that `CTE` examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need a script / program that construct old & new CategoryID mapping, and go through your Article table and replace it by looking up the map.

Maybe procedural program might do (if your DBMS supports procedural like stored proc / PLSQL), otherwise maybe it's easier to do this using Java / C# / Php